# NullPointerException in array of class Hut

Tags: java, arrays, error-handling, syntax-error, game-engine

I'm trying to design a pretty simple simulation civilization game for school. Right now I'm trying to make it so when you click this button on the control bar you make a new hut instance. I will put error report below and code where the error occurs.

Error Report:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at controls.Sidebar.clickBuildHut(Sidebar.java:102)
at screen_window.Game_Window.mouseClicked(Game_Window.java:248)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Code where error occurs:

```
public void newHut() {
        numOfHuts++;
        hut[numOfHuts] = new Hut(mouseX, mouseY, 0, numOfHuts);
}
```

Hut declaration at top of class:

```
Hut[] hut = new Hut[9999];
int numOfHuts;
```

Sidebar.clickBuildHut method:

```
public boolean clickBuildHut(int mouseX, int mouseY){
    if (viewConstruction){
        int topLeftX = x + 2;
        int topLeftY = y + 50 - 14;
        int selectionWidth = width - 10;
        int selectionHeight = 17;
        for (int i = 0; i <= width; i++) {
            for (int h = 0; h <= height; h++) {
                if (mouseX == topLeftX + i && mouseY == topLeftY + h) {
                    first_map.setEditMode(true);
                    game_window.newHut();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

first_map.setEditMode:

```
public void setEditMode(boolean editMode) {
    this.editMode = editMode;
}
```

Although I don't think that this is the problem because when this is switched to true I see the picture change correctly. If you want me to give you more information on this I can but, I don't think that it would be of any use since it isn't where the problem lies.

Comment: `Hut[] hut = new Hut[1234];`

Comment: are you initializing `hut` anywhere?

Comment: Your stack trace indicates that the NPE happens in the `clickBuildHut` method, but you've shown the `newHut` method.  Please show the `clickBuildHut` method.

Comment: You seem to want to create a dynamically sized collection.  Have you considered using a LinkedList<Hut> instead?

Comment: I don't know what a "LinkedList<Hut>" is. Could you please tell me what that is or provide an external link.

Comment: See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locate line 102 of Sidebar.java.  Based on the stack trace that is the location of the NPE.  By your code postings I would guess line 102 is either:

```
first_map.setEditMode(true);
```

or

```
game_window.newHut();
```

I say that because those are the only object references in the `clickBuildHut` method.  So, either `first_map` is null or `game_window` is null.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any place that you iniailize the `hut` array.  You've declared it, but you haven't initialized it, so Java defaults it to `null`.

Somewhere, you need to initialize it with something like this:

```
hut = new Hut[size];
```

perhaps in a constructor.

**EDIT**

Based on the question edit that now displays the `clickBuildHut` method, depending on which line is actually line 102, either `first_map` or `game_window` is `null`.

Comment: I changed my hut declaration to "Hut[] hut= new Hut[9999];" but I'm still receiving the same error.

I also tried seperating it so it is declared "Hut[] hut;" then later it is declared "hut = new Hut[9999]".

Comment: I added the method for first_map and explained why I don't think that, that is the problem.